# Escaping an apostrophe in Java

Tags: java, mysql, escaping

I'm still somewhat new to Java and trying to insert data into a database. I'm getting an error when inserting a string containing 's so my end result would be to escape the apostrophe. How can I accomplish?

Comment: "The crux of the biscuit is the apostrophe" - FZ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html) :

```java
StringEscapeUtils.escapeSql(yourstring);
```

*Caution* : As of Commons Lang 3.0 :

> **StringEscapeUtils.escapeSql**
>
> This was a misleading method, only handling the simplest of possible SQL cases. As SQL is not Lang's focus, it didn't make sense to maintain this method.

Comment: While I agree that using escapeSql can have it's negatives, there are places where prepared statements don't work well. For example, building an insert of many rows. That being said, some db drivers will allow you to combine many prepared statements into a batch and then automatically convert them into a single, more efficient statement. Knowing which to use when can take some research.

Answer (score 13):

Use prepared statements. As well as handling any special characters, they are much more robust and help prevent sql injection attacks.

Comment: +1 This answer gets to the heart of the issue: hand-coding your own SQL in your method calls is bad practice, and opens you up to a host of security issues.

Comment: A good habit to get into, but perhaps overkill for learning the language.

Comment: ... just ask Little Bobby Tables. :)

Answer (score 6):

The issue really isn't with Java, rather with the underlying database. Most likely you are stringing your parameters together like this:

```
  String sql = "select * from sometable where somefield = " + someObject.getSomeField();
```

Don't do that. Use [PreparedStatement](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)'s instead.

That has the added advantage of preventing SQL injection attacks, if this is an application that has to be concerned about such things.

Comment: +1: it not only saves you from SQL injection attacks, but it also eases setting Java objects inside a SQL statement (Date, InputStream, etc) and is technically also more performant (precompiled at DB).

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the database, but you can use '' in SqlServer.

EDIT: In MySql you can use a double apostrophe or backslash: http://www.faqts.com/knowledge_base/view.phtml/aid/630

Comment: Double apostrophe in postgres

Comment: And I'll agree with James in comment: use prepared statements. Much better long-term solution.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using a [java.sql.Statement](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html), and calling the executeQuery method with a String.  That's bad, because it's possible to do SQL injection.  You should use a [java.sql.PreparedStatement](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) instead, and then you can set any String that you want as a parameter, and you won't have your problem.

For example:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE MY_TABLE SET TEXT_FIELD = ?");
pstmt.setString(1, "any String 'will work here!");
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer Escape Apostrophe automatically using my Reflect util class. Soon I will share entire library.

```
/**
 * An automated Sql Escape Apostrophe before preparing an Object as Sql insert
 * query
 * 
 * @param obj
 * @return List of all field's values as string type
 */
public static Object escapeSql_Apostrophe(Object obj) {
    List<Field> fields = getDeclaredFields(obj);
    for (Field field : fields) {
        field.setAccessible(true); // Additional line
        String val = new String();
        // System.out.println("type : " + field.getType().getSimpleName());
        if (isPredfinedObject(field)) {
            try {
                val = field.get(obj) + "";
                if (val.contains("'")) {
                    val = val.replaceAll("'", "''");
                    String type = field.getType().getSimpleName();
                    if (type.equals(String.class.getSimpleName())) {
                        field.set(obj, val);
                    }
                    if (type.equals(Character.class.getSimpleName())) {
                        field.setChar(obj, val.charAt(0));
                    }
                }
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            try {
                System.out.println(field.get(obj));
                System.out.println(getAllFieldsValues(field.get(obj)));
                continue;
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's dependent on the database you are using.  Usually '' works (I only have firsthand knowledge with SQL Server).

What database are you using?